# union of two theories which doesn't contain same symbols of language has a model

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

let T1 and T2 be two theories in language L and none of the symbols of L occur in both T1 and T2, also both T1 and T2 has infinite model, how can i show the union of T1 and T2 has a model?
i first tried to take m1 as a model of T1 and m2 as a model of T2, i want to show that the union of m1 and th(m1) and m2 and th(m2) has a model, if not then there exists p in the union of m1 and th(m1) and a -p in the union of m2 and th(m2)
since T1 and T2 doesn't contain same symbols so this can not happen and the union of T1 and T2 must have a model.
or if i use the LST theorem then I have both T1 and T2 has model of cardinality $X_0$ but I don't know how to use this...

Answer (score 3):

By the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem, both $T_1$ and $T_2$ have a model of size $\kappa$ for some infinite $\kappa$. By transferring the structure, one may as well assume that the model has underlying set $\kappa$ for both.

Your new structure should be $\kappa$ with the symbols of $L$ appearing in $T_1$ interpreted as in the model of $T_1$, and the symbols of $L$ appearing in $T_2$ interpreted as in the model of $T_2$. Given the hypothesis, this is consistant. This new model should work

Comment: If $f$ is a binary function symbol in $T_1$, $a$ is a constant symbol in $T_1$, and $b$ is a constant symbol in $T_2,$ how do you interpret $f(a,b)$?

Comment: @ziggurism $a$ is interpreted as some element of $\kappa$. $b$ is interpreted as some element of $\kappa$. $f$ is interpreted as a function $\kappa^2\to \kappa$. So $f(a,b)$ makes sense, right?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. That’s why we have to decide what its value is. The model $M_1$ tells us what $f(a_1,a_2)$ will be. But how do we decide what $f(a,b)$ will be, or $f(b_1,b_2)$?

Comment: @ziggurism : $a$ is an element of $\kappa$, and so is $b$. As $f$ is already defined on $\kappa^2$, we don't have any more choices to make : $f(a,b)$ is *set in stone*. But its value won't matter, because neither $T_1$ nor $T_2$ "know" about it

Comment: @Max I think I see. We transfer one structure on $\kappa$ to the other copy modeling the other theory, so we get model of both. $f$ is defined on all of $\kappa$, including the elements which interpret constants from $M_2$. I was trying to imagine some kind of disjoint union structure.

Comment: Should i use back and forth to prove this?

Comment: Why would you ?

Comment: I don't know hot to formalize this....

Comment: Where do you have trouble ? What step is bothering you ?

Comment: I think to show the model has underlying set k for both i should use back and forth...

Comment: What are you calling back and forth ?

Comment: I don't get it how to define a function between T1 and T2 to make one of them to be the model of the union of two theories